# how to sync a backbone view with the attached model on bootstrap/creation?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Usually I have a View on which I set listeners to model-changes, like so (conflated):

```
var jsonModel = {bla: 'interesting stuff'}; //some model in json, probably rendered in a dom-element and passed from the server to the client

var someModelType =  Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  bla: "String"
});

var someModelInstance = new someModelType(jsonModel);

var someViewType = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model,'change:bla', function(model){
      //update view to sync with model change here
    }
  } 
});

var someViewInstance = new someViewType({
  model: someModelInstance
});
```

I'm looking for the preferred / backbone - way of bootstrapping the view, i.e: I want my view (form fields or what have you) to be synced with the model on creation. With the above this is impossible since the model is created before the view is attached, which results in model-updates/changes to be fired before listeners from the view were initialized.

Of course I could code some custom bootstapping logic which would call the listener-functions manually, but since this must be such a common problem, I'm looking on some best practice advice, or even better, a Backbone-switch I need to set to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sound silly, but what I usually do is do a render() after the view creation.

For me, the whole point of the change event is to notify of a change. The fact that it's triggered also on creation (as a "changed compared to the default") is more a side effect than   anything deep...

In that sense, when I create the views, and give it an existing model, I expect the model to be somewhat ready and so I should be able to do a render() right away. So my bootstrapping code would be more like:

```
var someViewInstance = new someViewType({
   model: someModelInstance
});
someViewInstance.render()
```

Or do it in the initialize() after bindings if you feel adventurous (I personally don't like that because when dealing with subviews, it's hard to know exactly when you want the render to happen, especially when dependent on libraries who need the DOM to be ready, and can't work on detached nodes).

So to sum up, although your problem is common, to me, it doesn't need any kind of complex solution: you have a render() function to transform your model into DOM-stuff, your model may or may not be ready but it exists, so you pass it to the view, and you do the first rendering after creating the view, manually, because you know it needs to happen. Then you bind to changes, in case your model is updated, to update the DOM accordingly.

side note: in case of a collection of models, when the Model isn't ready at ALL, then it probably shouldn't even have an instance, and you should let the Collection give you some add/remove events for when it pops into existence.